# Cordova camera plugin not working in Android mobile but working in emulator

Tags: android, apache, cordova, jquery-mobile, android-camera

I have developed an app to test the camera open in Android mobiles. I have followed the cordova camera API document. My code works fine and perfect in emulator, but not opening when I opens the camera in mobile.

Here is my code: config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<widget xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0" xmlns:vs="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2014/htmlapps" id="io.cordova.CameraTest" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets">
  <name>CameraTest</name>
  <description>A blank project that uses Apache Cordova to help you build an app that targets multiple mobile platforms: Android, iOS, Windows, and Windows Phone.</description>
  <author href="http://cordova.io" email="dev@cordova.apache.org">Apache Cordova Team </author>
  <content src="index.html" />
  <access origin="*" />
  <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
  <preference name="windows-target-version" value="8.0" />
  <preference name="windows-phone-target-version" value="8.1" />
  <vs:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.camera" version="0.3.2" />
  <vs:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.dialogs" version="0.2.10" />
  <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/device" />
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/camera"/>
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/file"/>
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/media"/>
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/network"/>
  <vs:platformSpecificValues />
</widget>
```

Js code:

```
document.addEventListener( 'deviceready', onDeviceReady.bind( this ), false );

    function onDeviceReady() {
        // Handle the Cordova pause and resume events
        pictureSource = navigator.camera.PictureSourceType;
        destinationType = navigator.camera.DestinationType;
        document.addEventListener( 'pause', onPause.bind( this ), false );
        document.addEventListener( 'resume', onResume.bind( this ), false );

        // TODO: Cordova has been loaded. Perform any initialization that requires Cordova here.
    };
```

script:

```
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>
<script>
         var pictureSource;
                var destinationType;
                function opencam() {

                    navigator.camera.getPicture(onsucess, onfail, {
                        quality: 50,
                        destinationType: destinationType.DATA_URL,
                        allowEdit: true,
                        targetWidth: 100,
                        targetHeight: 100,
                        saveToPhotoAlbum: false
                    });
                }

                function onsucess(imageData) {

                    debugger;
                }
                function onfail(message) {
                    alert("Error: " + message);
                    debugger;
                }
</script>
```

Its working fine in ripple emulator, but when I install in mobile, camera is opening at all.

Note: I don't have `androidmanifest.xml` file in my solution.

Comment: can't see why it's working fine in emulator, I can't see where you call the function 'opencam'?

Answer (score 0):

it's not very clear when you call the opencam() function, are you sure that you are calling it after the device ready ? Maybe the emulator is just slower and it executes the camera method after that the camera code is initialized while on device the call comes too soon.

Also do not use blocking method (debugger, alert) in callback from camera plugin I had problems with them (and I've seen some posts about it). Use console o display something on your page.

Last suggestion do not use DATA_URL to retrieve the image, using this option cordova pass a base64 string with the image but the image could be very big on your real device (and worst base64 is 30% bigger than the original format) so it can easily crash your app. Try using FILE_URI it's way better.

Hope this helps

Comment: <input type="button" id="btncamera" value="Open Camera" onclick="opencam();" /> ---> this the code i use to call... its in index page, ondeviceready function is in index.js page... Opencam script is in index page...

Comment: But do you see the camera app staring and then you don't get the image or you don't even see the camera app ?

Comment: I can see the camera app, but when i click open camera button it is not doing anything.. In emulator it works perfectly opening camera with select files and cancel button.. Main reason I found today is its not hitting the ondeviceready function in mobile alone

Comment: if it doesn't hit ondeviceready maybe you have a problem in your package. Do you have cordova.js loaded ? Are you trying using ios or Android ? try to see platform logs, adb for android, xcode logs for ios. Maybe you can see an error there

Comment: yes cordova is loading in solution, not in build, i dont find cordova.js inside build folder

Comment: cordova.js is added from cordova when you build the project because is platform specific, just make sure to have it running. What patform are you using ? ios or android ?

Comment: So try to run the application on the device connected with your computer then openup chrome and inside devices (insert url chrome://inspect/#devices) you should see your app running and you can inspect and debug it placing breakpoint. This should help you find the problem